# How to rename "Primary output from MyProject (Active)" and .exe

Tags: c#, build, installation, windows-installer

I am brand new to building and deploying Windows Forms applications, so new that I'm not even sure "build" and "deploy" are the correct terms. I read [this excellent guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/creating-an-msi-package-for-C-Sharp-windows-application-using-a-v/) to creating an installer for my application, and I mimicked it almost exactly.

I have a winform project UmfExtract and a setup project UmfExtractSetup that installs UmfExtract . After installation, however, on Windows 10, an icon appears at the top of the start menu, under Recently Added: "Shortcut to Primary output from UmfExtract (Active)." I want to rename that to just "Shortcut to UmfExtract" or just "UmfExtract." Additionally, in the installation directory, the .exe and the .exe.config are the same as the original name of my project when I first created it, PythonExecuter. How do I change PythonExecuter.exe to UmfExtract.exe? Elsewhere on the user's computer, the application is named correctly. On the desktop, the shortcut icon says "UmfExtract," which is correct.

In all my research on this, people have said to change the Assembly name. I have done that. The Assembly name is UmfExtract:
[image: Assembly name]

I looked into the Outputs property of the Primary output object: 
[image: Primary Outputs outputs screen]

The AssemblyTitle and AssemblyProduct in AssemblyInfo.cs have been changed to UmfExtract:
[image: AssemblyInfo.cs]

What else could I possibly be missing? Could I perhaps accidentally be installing an older build of my project? I right-click on each project in the Solution Explorer and click Build (while the Debug/Release drop down box in Visual Studio is set to Release), then I navigate to the Setup project on my local machine and go to \Release\UmfExtractSetup.msi. I imagine that .msi file is updated/overwritten to the new information each time I Build the projects. Could it be that I'm building wrong?

Comment: Select the shortcut in the setup project.  Change its Name property in Properties window.

Comment: @HansPassant There are two shortcuts in the Setup project, one under User's Desktop and one under User's Programs Menu\UmfExtract. Both shortcuts are named UmfExtract. In Application Folder, there is an object (not a shortcut) called "Primary output from EmfExtract (Active)". Its Type is listed as Output. There is no name property on that object, and there is no rename option for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what was wrong, but the problem has been fixed. I believe the error was in the build process. I believe I was installing an old build of the project. I clicked Build > Clean Solution from the menu bar, then Build > Build Solution. I also right-clicked the UmfExtract project and then clicked Clean, then Build, and I also right-clicked the UmfExtractSetup project and then clicked Build (there was no Clean option in the right-click menu for the Setup project).